# ASP.NET MVC solution for OpenID + OAuth + trivial authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth, openid, registration

Is there a de-facto solution for ASP.NET MVC 3+ one should use in case he needs to allow users to sign in/up via:

- OpenID
- OAuth
- Trivial registration / manual authentication

?

What I'm basically looking for is "Membership API" that works for OpenID, OAuth and whatever else. Key features are:

- Roles support (for ASP.NET MVC)
- Ability to bind multiple auth methods to single user (for instance, somebody first signed up with "trivial registration", then he wants to bind his Google account and then his Yahoo account, so he should be able to auth with any of these 3)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) is your friend.

See this blog post: [OpenID Authentication with ASP.NET MVC3 , DotNetOpenAuth and OpenID-Selector](http://weblogs.asp.net/haithamkhedre/archive/2011/03/13/openid-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc3-dotnetopenauth-and-openid-selector.aspx)

Also, you can see [the official tutorial on ASP.NET MVC](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/programmatic-openid-relying-party/).

Comment: Last link is dead, but I *think* this is the new one: [Creating an openid relying party (programatically)](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Creating-an-openid-relying-party-%28programatically%29). I never saw the old link when alive so I am not 100% sure on the new link.

Answer (score 4):

Please visit this links:- you can find a good solution....

1. [OpenID Authentication with ASP.NET MVC3 , DotNetOpenAuth and OpenID-Selector](http://weblogs.asp.net/haithamkhedre/archive/2011/03/13/openid-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc3-dotnetopenauth-and-openid-selector.aspx)
2. And you can download code from the [SocialAuth-net project](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/) and modify source code and implement. I have also done this, from here.